# MySQL Search / Replace - Switching root domain on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Multisite installation, and the root domain is set to root-domain.com. I would like to switch it with one of the sites of the network (site-in-network.com), and make it a root domain.

This way site-in-network.com would become the root domain, and root-domain.com would become one of the sites in the network (100+ sites).

I've done search and replace on a database before, and it worked, but I was dropping a domain all together, so I just replaced domain-a.com with domain-b.com. This time it is different, I want to keep both of them, and just switch the positions in the database.

I guess I would need to run a MySQL query. As far as I know, the root domain was set to something like "www.root-domain.com", and all other sites in the network were like "site-in-network.com" (without the .www part)

The database is about 0.5GB, so it would be good to get it right the first time.

Thank you in advance for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a search and replace, but mind you that wordpress is also storing site information in a serialized form in the tables. That means that a default search and replace will break a lot of stuff, so be careful with that.

There is however a script that takes this into account: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Download it and put it in your root folder. (And afterwards, delete it!!)

Using this script you could change root-domain.com to root-domain.tmp.com and then site-in-network.com to root-domain.com. After that you could rename root-domain.tmp.com to site-in-network.com. Basicly what Plamen Nikolov suggested to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a little bit of a craftily solution:**

You can still workaround the situation with the *find and replace* technique using fake domain name:

1. Replace *site-in-network.com* with *some-fake-unique-name.com*
2. Replace *root-domain.com* with *site-in-network.com*
3. Finally *some-fake-unique-name.com* with *root-domain.com*.

There is also solution without changing the database, by definining HOME and SITE URL like here: [Changing the Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL)